# how to call a function when Data table column visibility change

Tags: jquery, datatables

how to call a function when **Data table** column visibility  change (NP: function must be call each changes in column visibility popup) ,  and get index of current visible columns .

Comment: jquery datatable or asp.net or something else?

Comment: Share your code. What have you tried?